# Why won't local modules load using Cloud Functions for Firebase

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, module, google-cloud-functions

I've found out that Cloud Functions for Firebase uses the `package.json` file to load [dependencies](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/handle-dependencies), but I get an error when calling my functions:

```
Code in file index.js can't be loaded.
Did you list all required modules in the package.json dependencies?
Detailed stack trace: Error: Cannot find module 'express'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:469:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:417:25)
    at Module.require (module.js:497:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:20:19)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/user_code/rest_api.js:2:17)
    at Module._compile (module.js:570:32)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:579:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:487:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:446:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:438:3)
```

Here is my `index.js` file:

```
const processor = require('./processor.js');

exports.processThing = functions.https.onRequest((req, res) => {
    let param = req.body.param;
    processor.process(param);
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't include the file extension when [requiring Node modules](https://medium.freecodecamp.org/requiring-modules-in-node-js-everything-you-need-to-know-e7fbd119be8). Your `require` should read:

```
const processor = require('./processor');
```

The Firebase CLI should take care of the rest. It will bundle it like the dependencies your `package.json` requires.

Answer (score 0):

You need to install express module dependency in to package.json file with following command 
    **npm install express**  just make sure you installing on right folder means you need to install it into **functions** folder

like ~/NodejsProjects/AMZFIRE/**functions**$ npm install express

then you will see in package.json

"dependencies": {

```
    "express": "^4.16.3"

 }
```

Thats it !!!